# How to change Xamarin forms default webview browser to google chrome

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, google-authentication

In my application i want to change default webview browser

XAML

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Grid.Row="1" Navigated="webView_Navigated">
</WebView>
```

C#

```
WebView web = new WebView()
{
    Source = res.url,
};
webView.Source = web.Source;
```

When i am trying using like this facing issue with google authentication 
error :
**this browser or app may not be secure.**

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Actually , The webview  in android is based on Chrome , check 
 https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview.

Answer (score 0):

The message "this browser or app may not be secure." is not caused by the web view. You need to check the URL and the configuration.

Addressing the original question WebView is not very configurable. Xamarin Essentials have "Browser" but it is even less.

If you want to have more control over the web renderer you need to approach the problem with custom renderer using WebKit (for  Android) and UIWebView (for iOS) controls.